# how to prepare video in advanced like tiktok before user scrolling? , flutter android ios

Tags: android, ios, flutter, networking, video

I've making tiktok clone coding by myself

I'm using flutter videoplayer package so i can play network video very easily

but there is one major problem, it's delay.

there is 1-2sec delay to play network video.

how can I reduce delay or prepare video in advance??

so, user cannot notice delay at all like tiktok?

you don't need to full answer I just need a clue to study or dive in

literally, I know nothing about these network video part.

somebody,anybody help me

Comment: Since you have a way to find and load a video, you should be able to load more than one at a time. Look into something called concurrency or multi threading to get started. With this you can load several videos at one time, and send them to the feed as soon as they are loaded.

Comment: fetch it before you even show it to the user

Comment: I don't know about flutter but for android studio have a look at [Video Cache](https://github.com/danikula/AndroidVideoCache)

Answer (score 0):

you have to use initialise the controller with the url so that it start downloading the videos before the user get to that screen.

what u can do, u can apply a state management tool like getx. wen the user start scrolling, u start adding more urls to the list controller so that it downloads the video before the user get to that screen